# Name for the view that ambiguities in natural language are imperfections of it?

Tags: terminology, philosophy-of-language, formal-semantics

For instance, in natural language, "or" is slightly different from logical OR, "some" is slightly different from logical EXISTS, etc.

What is the name of the belief that these discrepancies are actually imperfections of natural language -- that if we all spoke in the language of a formal system, everything would be much better?

Comment: "Nonsense" is what I'd call it ;) I don't think you'll find a specifically linguistic term because it wouldn't be a common belief amongst linguists.

Comment: Conlangers might say ["ANADEW"](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/790/113) but it has a broader meaning.

Comment: Are you looking for the term "prescriptivism"?

Comment: @curiousdannii While true, a lot of linguistic-looking nonsense topics have common names: linguistic determinism/strong Sapir-Whorf, for example, or Proto-World/Nostratic reconstruction, or Edenics…

Comment: ["the hobgoblin of small minds"](https://www.google.ch/search?q=%22foolish+consistency%22)

Comment: Sticklers, grammar Nazis, formalist, idealist, reductionist, minimalist, purist, structuralist, prescriptivist ... in the end, the name you ask for depends on the specific view, so your example based on binary logic would need a source to show that such theory even exists in linguistics. For a general answer try english.SE